# ¿como evitar perder el focus de lector de codigo de barras al minimizar aplicacion?

Tags: c#

bueno estoy haciendo una aplicacion en c# que involucra la utilización de un 
código de barras , bueno cuando ejecuto la aplicacion el lector funciona de maravilla
 pero cuando minimizo la aplicacion el lector deja de funcionar , como puedo hacer que 
cuando minimize la aplicacion el lector pueda seguir trabajando

Comment: Entiendo que estas utilizando un lector que simula la lectura como si fuera un teclado, ¿cierto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los lectores de código de barras en general actúan como si fueran un teclado normal.
Una vez que tu aplicación pierde el foco, los eventos de teclado (lógicamente) no se pasan a ella (porqué iban a pasarse? Para que iba tu aplicación querer recibir lo que estás escribiendo en un documento word por ejemplo).

Pero si hay una solución. Para conseguirlo, debes hacer uso de los *ganchos de teclado globales* (global keyboard hooks), que básicamente lo que hace es suscribirse al sistema de mensajes del Sistema Operativo para capturar las pulsaciones de teclado.

A continuación te pongo un código sacado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384189/579895) en el que he traducido los comentarios, que puede servirte para lo que quieres:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SnagFree.TrayApp.Core
{
    class GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs : HandledEventArgs
    {
        public GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState KeyboardState { get; private set; }
        public GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent KeyboardData { get; private set; }

        public GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(
            GlobalKeyboardHook.LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent keyboardData,
            GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState keyboardState)
        {
            KeyboardData = keyboardData;
            KeyboardState = keyboardState;
        }
    }

    //Basado en https://gist.github.com/Stasonix
    class GlobalKeyboardHook : IDisposable
    {
        public event EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> KeyboardPressed;

        public GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            _hookProc = LowLevelKeyboardProc; // debemos mantener vivo _hookProc, proque el RB(GC) no es consciente del comportamiento de SetWindowsHookEx.

            _user32LibraryHandle = LoadLibrary("User32");
            if (_user32LibraryHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Fallo al cargar la biblioteca 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }



            _windowsHookHandle = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, _hookProc, _user32LibraryHandle, 0);
            if (_windowsHookHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Fallo al ajustar los  ganchos de teclado para '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
            }
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // proque solo podemos "desengancharnos" en el mismo hilo, no en el recolector de basura
                if (_windowsHookHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    if (!UnhookWindowsHookEx(_windowsHookHandle))
                    {
                        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                        throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Fallo al desenganchar los ganchos de teclado para '{Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName}'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                    }
                    _windowsHookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;


                    _hookProc -= LowLevelKeyboardProc;
                }
            }

            if (_user32LibraryHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                if (!FreeLibrary(_user32LibraryHandle)) /
                {
                    int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new Win32Exception(errorCode, $"Fallo al descargar biblioteca 'User32.dll'. Error {errorCode}: {new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()).Message}.");
                }
                _user32LibraryHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
            }
        }

        ~GlobalKeyboardHook()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        private IntPtr _windowsHookHandle;
        private IntPtr _user32LibraryHandle;
        private HookProc _hookProc;

        delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

        /// <summary>
        /// La función SetWindowsHookEx instala un gancho (hook) de aplicación en una cadena de ganchos.
        /// Los ganchos se instalan para monitorizar el sistema en busca de ciertos tipos de eventos. 
        /// Estos eventos estan asociados o bien con un hilo específico o bien con todos los hilo en el mismo escritorio como el hilo que llamaThese events are
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="idHook">tipo de gancho</param>
        /// <param name="lpfn">procedimiento de gancho</param>
        /// <param name="hMod">handle a la instancia de la aplicación</param>
        /// <param name="dwThreadId">identificador del hilo</param>
        /// <returns>Si la función lo consigue, el valor de retorno es un handle a procedimiento de gancho.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, int dwThreadId);

        /// <summary>
        /// La función UnhookWindowsHookEx elimina un procedimiento de enganche instalado en una cadena de enganches por la función SetWindowsHookEx.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hhk">handle al procedimiento de enganche</param>
        /// <returns>Si la función lo consigue, el valor de retorno es true.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);

        /// <summary>
        /// La función CallNextHookEx pasa la información del gancho al siguiente procedimiento de enganche en la cadena de enganches actual.
        /// Un procedimiento de enganche pueda llamar a esta función antes o despues de procesar la información.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hHook">handle del enganche actual</param>
        /// <param name="code">código del gancho pasado al procedimiento del gnacho</param>
        /// <param name="wParam">valor pasado al procedimiento de enganche</param>
        /// <param name="lParam">valor pasado al procedimiento de enganche</param>
        /// <returns>Si la función lo consigue, el valor de retorno es true.</returns>
        [DllImport("USER32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, int code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Código de tecla virtual. El código debe ser un valor en el rango 1-254.
            /// </summary>
            public int VirtualCode;

            /// <summary>
            /// Código de hardware para la tecla. 
            /// </summary>
            public int HardwareScanCode;

            /// <summary>
            /// La bandera de tecla extendida, banderas de inyección de evento, código de contexto, y bandera de estado de transición. Este miembro está especificado de la manera siguiente: Una aplicación puede usar los valores siguientes para comprobar las banderas de pulsación de teclado. Comprobar LLKHF_INJECTED (bit 4) te dirá si el ebento fue inyectado. Si lo fue, comprobar LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED (bit 1) te dirá si el evento fué inyectado desde un proceso que corre en un nivel mas bajo de integridad.
            /// </summary>
            public int Flags;

            /// <summary>
            /// La marca de tiempo para este mensaje, equivalente a lo que GetMessageTime devolvería para este mensaje.
            /// </summary>
            public int TimeStamp;

            /// <summary>
            /// Información adicional asociada al mensaje. 
            /// </summary>
            public IntPtr AdditionalInformation;
        }

        public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        //const int HC_ACTION = 0;

        public enum KeyboardState
        {
            KeyDown = 0x0100,
            KeyUp = 0x0101,
            SysKeyDown = 0x0104,
            SysKeyUp = 0x0105
        }

        public const int VkSnapshot = 0x2c;
        //const int VkLwin = 0x5b;
        //const int VkRwin = 0x5c;
        //const int VkTab = 0x09;
        //const int VkEscape = 0x18;
        //const int VkControl = 0x11;
        const int KfAltdown = 0x2000;
        public const int LlkhfAltdown = (KfAltdown >> 8);

        public IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            bool fEatKeyStroke = false;

            var wparamTyped = wParam.ToInt32();
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(KeyboardState), wparamTyped))
            {
                object o = Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent));
                LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent p = (LowLevelKeyboardInputEvent)o;

                var eventArguments = new GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(p, (KeyboardState)wparamTyped);

                EventHandler<GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs> handler = KeyboardPressed;
                handler?.Invoke(this, eventArguments);

                fEatKeyStroke = eventArguments.Handled;
            }

            return fEatKeyStroke ? (IntPtr)1 : CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SnagFree.TrayApp.Core
{
    internal class Controller : IDisposable
    {
        private GlobalKeyboardHook _globalKeyboardHook;

        public void SetupKeyboardHooks()
        {
            _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
            _globalKeyboardHook.KeyboardPressed += OnKeyPressed;
        }

        private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs e)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine(e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode);

            if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode != GlobalKeyboardHook.VkSnapshot)
                return;

            // seems, not needed in the life.
            //if (e.KeyboardState == GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState.SysKeyDown &&
            //    e.KeyboardData.Flags == GlobalKeyboardHook.LlkhfAltdown)
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show("Alt + Print Screen");
            //    e.Handled = true;
            //}
            //else

            if (e.KeyboardState == GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState.KeyDown)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Print Screen");
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _globalKeyboardHook?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Otra opción es usar alguna librería ya existente,como por ejemplo esta en [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET).

Edit:

Tras pensarlo, tienes otro problema con esta solución. Como distingues que lo que llega proviene del lector de código de barras? Si no me equivoco, algunos permiten configurar una "cadena de control" previa al código de barras en si. Si no es así, se complica bastante la solución.

<sub>He traducido *hook* como *gancho*, a falta de otro sinónimo mas exacto</sub>